# How to set Route Prefix in conventional routing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms, routes

I am having an old Asp.Net Web Form application where I am mapping urls using conventional routing. 
Now I want to add a common prefix to all the aspx pages.

> One solution is - I can manually add the prefix in all the url patterns one by one.

Is there any way to make it common?

Note: I can not use AttributeRouting. Please suggest something in conventional routing.

Comment: Please refer this [link](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/url-routing-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series)

Comment: @jishansiddique This link does not resolve my issue. I have multiple routes and all of them has a common prefix. I want to make it common.